# User not responding to method in rspec -User Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:method)}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am having failing Rspec tests that I cannot determine what I am doing wrong.

Here is my User Spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
   before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
          password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   end

   subject { @user }

   it { should respond_to(:courses)}
   it { should respond_to(:take_course!)} # this test fails
   it { should respond_to(:taking_course?)} # this test fails as well

end
```

Here is my user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :assignments, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :assignments

  def take_course!
  end

  def taking_course?
  end
end
```

I dont have anything in the method yet, but I am confused as to why its not responding to it.

Comment: Are you using any test preloaders like spork?

Comment: Yes! Had to restart it, stupid mistake. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vimsha, pointed out - I was using Spork as the test preloader, and simply needed to restart Spork.